# namespace defined in autoload psr-4 using in laravel 5 app.php giving not found error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, psr-4

stucked my heads in some errors.i dont getting where i have done my mistake.
I am using `laravel 5` and installed it.I want to use `l5-repository` so i installed https://github.com/prettus/l5-repository this repository using `composer` commnad:

```
composer require prettus/l5-repository
```

and i made all changes as per installation document and its working fine.

after installing repository using composer my directory structure is as below:

```
curovis
|-- composer.json
|-- composer.lock
|-- app
|-- bootstarp
|-- config
|-- database
`-- vendor
    |-- composer
    `-- prettus
        `-- l5-repository
            |-- src
            |   `-- Prettus
            |       `-- Repository
            `-- composer.json
```

after this as per doc i have made following entry in `/var/www/curovis/config/app.php`:
`Prettus\Repository\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider::class,`
and its working fine.
Now i want to change `composer.json` of root directory entry as following:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Prettus\\Repository\\": "vendor/prettus/l5-repository/src/Prettus"
        }
    },
```

and use `composer update` command. it also works fine.
now i want use same repo with another name so i have change `composer.json` with follwing:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "RepoTest\\Repository\\": "vendor/repotest/l5-repository/src/RepoTest"
        }
    },
```

and add `RepoTest\Repository\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider::class,` in `app.php` file.run `composer update` command. then it gives following error:

```
FatalErrorException in /var/www/curovis/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php line 146: Class 'RepoTest\Repository\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider' not found
```

i cant understand why laravel is looking for `/var/www/curovis/vendor/laravel/framework/src` this path instead of provided as `"RepoTest\\Repository\\": "vendor/repotest/l5-repository/src/RepoTest"` in composer.json.
is anything i am missing or any error in composer.
Thanks for help.

Comment: If you just want to use another name why don't you use and alias in your config/app.php instead of changing it on composer.json

Comment: i want to change entire repository structure,so i want to go step by step process.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sovled above error by changing composer entry:
when i have see `autoload_classmap.php` and `autoload_psr4.php` files of `/vendor/composer/` folder `autoload_classmap.php` file does not contain namespace that i require.
so i have made following change in my `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database","vendor/repotest/src/Repotest/Repository/"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Repotest\\Repository\\": "vendor/repotest/src/Repotest/Repository/"
        }
    },
```

so by making entry in `"classmap":` make entry in `autoload_classmap.php` and working fine now.
Thanks @sven for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You NEVER add autoloading for the packages you added inside your main `composer.json`. The path "vendor" should never appear there.

I recognize you are trying to add a package, then modify it and use that instead. You changed the autoloading prefix from "Prettus" to "RepoTest", but did you also change the namespace in the PHP files? Simply renaming the path does not affect the PHP class names and namespaces, so if you rename a file, and inside that file there is no matching class defined, autoloading will fail.

Whatever it is you are trying to do, I think it is a good idea to ask about that instead of asking to fix problems you think are necessary because of the way you do solve your original problem. If you want to know how to modify an existing project and use your variant of it: Ask about it.

Comment: yes. may be this issue.Can you please tell me the path or file in laravel 5 in which i have to make entry for autoload?

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/helper.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
}
```

Default Composer file to load.